# How to push multiple array list in one array using java

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, datatable

I am using java programing and I have some issue with making json object.

For Ex. I want below response for datatable pagination

Output: 1 :-

```
{
    "recordsFiltered": 142728,
    "data": [
        ["1", "Bombuflat", "1"],
        ["1", "Bombuflat", "1"],
        ["1", "Bombuflat", "1"],
        ["2", "Garacharma", "1"],
        ["2", "Garacharma", "1"],
        ["2", "Garacharma", "1"],
        ["3", "Port Blair", "1"],
        ["3", "Port Blair", "1"],
        ["3", "Port Blair", "1"],
        ["4", "Rangat", "1"]
    ]
}
```

but I am getting reponse as:

Output: 2 :-

```
{
    "recordsFiltered": 142728,
    "data": [{
        "1",
        "Bombuflat",
        "1"
    }, {
        "1",
        "Bombuflat",
        "1"
    }, {
        "1",
        "Bombuflat",
        "1"
    }, {
        "2",
        "Garacharma",
        "1"
    }, {
        "2",
        "Garacharma",
        "1"
    }, {
        "2",
        "Garacharma",
        "1"
    }, {
        "3",
        "Port Blair",
        "1"
    }, {
        "3",
        "Port Blair",
        "1"
    }, {
        "3",
        "Port Blair",
        "1"
    }, {
        "4",
        "Rangat",
        "1"
    }]
}
```

and datatable throwing an error as unknow format

How can I make the json string as Output: 1

Thanks

Comment: How do you build Ouput 2 ? Which API are you using, what is the Object you are trying to jsonify ? And please put your output in <code>. More info about what your are doing now could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JSONArray` with two `JSONObject`s and your second `JSONObject` should contain a `JSONArray` to achieve your goal represented as *Output-1*.